# изменение свойства элемента в iframe

Tags: javascript

Есть iframe в котором есть текс между тэгами `<p>text</p>`. Доступ к этому элементу собственно получить удается, без проблем. Но когда нужно поменять его значение, совсем не получается. Текст беру следующим образом-

```
   var msg_content = window.frames['mail_message_ifr'].contentDocument.getElementById('tinymce').firstChild.innerHTML // это - text
.....

    msg_content = "another text"; // таким образом ничего не происходит
```

Как можно поменять это свойство

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать функцию в iframe, а необходимый текст передавать аргументом. Вызов функции будете делать из родителя, также через **contentWindow**

Answer (score 0):

Сайт и сайт в iframe на одном домене?
Политика безопасности браузера не позволяет получать доступ к dom,js, cookie для разных доменов.

Comment: на одном домене + ко всему, если после обьявления переменной которая хранит тот самый текст менять свойство -> `window.frames['mail_message_ifr'].contentDocument.getElementById('tinymce').firstChild.innerHTML = "new text"` - то меняет (сама переменная msg_content в одном и том же методе)

Answer (score 0):

```html
var msg_content = window.frames['mail_message_ifr'].contentDocument.getElementById('tinymce').firstChild;
.....

msg_content.innerHTML = "another text";
```